# Confused about the urls in app-engine-patch

Tags: django, google-app-engine, url

In app-engine-patch (http://code.google.com/p/app-engine-patch/)  ...

How on earth does the sample application know that the /person url maps to the myapp application?

I'm trying to understand the url structure to everything and
I've looked through the urls and I can't see it anywhere...

Source can be seen on mercurial here:

http://bitbucket.org/gumptioncom/appenginepatch-sample/src/

The application is running here:

http://aep-sample.appspot.com/

If anyone could help me out on this one I'd really appreciate it, thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So I figured it out for anyone that wants to know ...

The url mapping that sends /person to myapp is in the urlsauto.py file under the myapp directory.

You can see it clearly here:

http://bitbucket.org/gumptioncom/appenginepatch-sample/src/tip/myapp/urlsauto.py